# Unable to select more than 1 radio button

Tags: vb.net, winforms, radio-button

I have 4 radio buttons, r1, r2, r3, r4. These four radio buttons are in a group box.

r1 and r2 for asking the gender of person.

> r1 for Male , r2 for Female

r3 and r4 for asking whether the user would like to continue.

> r3 for Yes , r4 for No.

When I click r1 , r3 becomes unchecked and vice versa. Similar is the case with r2 , r4. So at a time I can check only one radio button. How can I get around this problem . The groupbox is essential so I cannot remove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Radiobuttons` are grouped by their parent-control. It would be sufficient to re-group them in a `Panel`.

Current Layout:

```
Groupbox
    RadioButton
    RadioButton
    RadioButton
    RadioButton
```

New Layout:

```
Groupbox
    Panel
        RadioButton
        RadioButton
    Panel
        RadioButton
        RadioButton
```

Comment: Is there any method to separate them ...like in html the radio buttons with the same name acted as 1 group

Comment: see the remarks here for confirmation of Bobby's reply  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the gender radio buttons and the yes/no radio buttons do not belong to the same radio button group - they need to be separate radio button lists.

Answer (score 1):

You can only select 1 Radiobutton in a Groupbox if there is no other subcontrol like Panel

So you have to create a Groupbox for `r1` and `r2`

and a separate for `r3` and `r4`

Answer (score 1):

Group Box = you have to select only one radio button. Use two Group Boxes instead, one for the gender and one for asking whether to continue.

Answer (score 1):

For radiobutton r1 and r2 use `GroupName = "Gender"`

For radiobutton r3 and r4 use `GroupName = "ContinueOrNot"`

Comment: There is no such property in WinForms...do you mean WPF?

Comment: Sorry...I don't mark your tag "winform". Yes I mean WPF(Visual Studio 2010)